# Promiscuous Mode on VMware capturing only broadcast

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, wireshark, network-traffic, promiscuous

I'm facing an issue with using promiscuous mode on VMware. I have 3 VMs connected to a single portgroup on which promiscuous mode has been enabled. It's changed to "Accept". I am monitoring traffic between the first 2 VMs on the 3rd VM. All 3 VMs are in the same subnet. Well, I've disabled IP services on the 3rd VM so it behaves like a proper passive interface.

The problem I'm facing is that all the monitoring VM is capturing on wireshark is broadcasts. Broadcasts such as ARP and DHCP Discovers. I'm initiating HTTP traffic or ICMP pings between the VMs, and while all of this communication is successful, I do not see the corresponding traffic on my monitoring VM. Why is this the case?

[image: wireshark capture]

Portgroup Settings
[image]